# ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app to App Store Connect. However, when I upload to App Store Connect, I get an e-mail with the following error:

> ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty.
>   Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and
>   resubmit it.

There's only one problem with the suggestion - I *am* using the latest build of Xcode.

This comes after uploading directly to App Store Connect from Xcode. Also, previous research indicates I should export using the "Save for iOS App Store Distribution" option, but this option is no longer listed as an option under "Export."

Having said that, however, I did have to restore my xcodeproj file from a previous Git commit, so maybe that messed something up. What do you suggest I do to solve this error?

Comment: are you using swift libraries in your project?

Comment: does anyone got the fix for it ? me too facing the same issue